# Regex to accept alphanumeric and some special character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Javascript regex like this:

```
/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/
```

I want to modify this regex so that it accept all capital and non-capital alphabets, all the numbers and some special characters: `- , _, @, ., /, #, &, +`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I hope this regex isn't used to filter password characters

Comment: Dig into some free, online information about using regexes. https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 98, accepted):

use:

```
/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/
```

You can also use the [character class](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html) \w to replace `A-Za-z0-9_`

Comment: I forgot to mention. This should also accept whitespace. I will accept your answer then.

Comment: what else is left? "." covers all:     **/^.*$/**

Comment: How to validate if string ends with /, where the provided answer is not working for me though it contains invalid characters.

Comment: In my regex, it accepts alphanumeric characters,-,\,/ .what is the format for this? I used /^[ A-Za-z0-9\/-]+$/ this.but its not working

Comment: /^[ A-Za-z_'-]*$/.test("djdjddhj'")

If you're checking for single names to only allow alphabets, a hyphen, an apostrophe this works fine returns true or false

Comment: how to alter this to restrict it between 8 and 24 characters only?

Comment: @FirasSCMP instead of the `*` character, replace with `{8,24}` https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC9

Comment: try this one
^[ A-Za-z0-9_,\/-]*$  -- Special Characters we can add multiple 

Example link https://regex101.com/r/RThDz5/1

Answer (score 23):

> I forgot to mention. This should also accept whitespace.

You could use:

```
/^[-@.\/#&+\w\s]*$/
```

Note how this makes use of the [character classes `\w` and `\s`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

**EDIT**:- Added \ to escape /

Comment: it would also accept newlines,tabs..:)

Comment: @Anirudh: Which in my book all fall under the definition of "whitespace". In any event, the regex is trivial to modify to exactly match the OP's requirements, whatever those might be.

Comment: hi, is there any way the textbox does not allow only (") and (')  in textbox using regex