# Modify a existing regex to include some special characters

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have a column ('branch') on which I am performing data cleaning, basically I want to retain only alphanumeric along with some special character like, "-", "/", "(", ")", spaces

Currently this is my code (retains only alphanumeric):

```
  library (stringr)

  df$branch1 <- str_replace_all(new_nodup$branch, "[\\W]", "")
```

I tired to use the following but this didn't work:

[Regex to accept alphanumeric and some special character in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439917/regex-to-accept-alphanumeric-and-some-special-character-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you need to keep spaces? Try `"[^\\w\\s/()-]"`

Comment: `\\w` includes the underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may include the characters you want to keep into a *negated character class*:

```
"[^\\w/()-]"
```

If you need to keep spaces, too, use

```
"[^\\w\\s/()-]"
```

Sample code:

```
df$branch1 <- str_replace_all(new_nodup$branch, "[^\\w\\s()/-]", "")
```

Comment: Just a note about `_`: since `[^\\w]` does not match underscores, you can replace `\\w` with `[:alpha:]` (if you want to remove underscores).