# HTML5 Pattern Validation

Tags: regex, html, validation

I'm trying to make a password field with the following requirements.

- Minimum of 8 characters
- Max of 16 characters
- Must contain one number OR special characters
- Only the following special characters may be used:

  , ` ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ) ; ' [ ] "{ } .

I read [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439917/regex-to-accept-alphanumeric-and-some-special-character-in-javascript) and tried to follow what was going on in the example. This is what I came up with:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9.,`~!@#$%^&*\);'\[\]\"\{\}.]).{8,16}+
```

This is how I'm using the pattern:

```
<input id="Password" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9.,`~!@#$%^&amp;*\);'\[\]\&quot;\{\}.]).{8,16}+" required="required" type="password">
```

This regex expression, however, does not seem to be working as intended. If I enter "password" as my input it should be rejected. Instead, this string is being accepted. I would greatly appreciate it if someone can give me a hand with this.

Comment: Is there code, which creates the password field and uses the regex?

Comment: Why does your regex have `[a-zA-Z]` at the beginning? You do not have a requirement that the string should start with an ASCII letter.

Comment: The password field is simply an input field in a form. I have included an example in my original post just now.

Comment: _"I'm trying to make a password field with the following requirements"_ - please don't. Nothing is more annoying than having to deviate from my usual "scheme" for creating passwords, just because some site thinks it knows better what "security" is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use the `pattern` attribute:

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="(?=.*[\d,`~!@#$%^&*);'[\]\x22{}.]).{8,16}" title="Please check the input!"/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

You only need to "escape" the double quote as `\x22` and the `]` symbol inside the character class.

No anchors are required since the `pattern` is anchored by default.

Comment: Note that `{8,16}+` is a *possessive* limiting quantifier that is not supported in JS regex, the `+` is ignored. `&` can be used as a literal. Same goes for a single apostrophe. Double quote needs "normalizing" as `\x22`. And no need of `^` and `$` here, the pattern is later enclosed with `^(?:` and `)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would check your password according to your rules (though in 2 regexes)

```
var psw = 'yourPas$word';
if (
    // ensure the length is between 8 & 16
    /^.{8,16}$/.test(psw) && 
    // ensure the presence of a special char
    /^.*[,`~!@#$%^&*);'\[\]"{}.].*$/.test(psw)
    ) {
    console.log('hurray is valid');
} else {
    console.log('booo');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matyas! Is it possible to do this as an input pattern all in one line?

Ex:  
``<input id="Password" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9.,`~!@#$%^&amp;*\);'\[\]\&quot;\{\}.]).{8,16}+" required="required" type="password">``

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex in pattern to make sure the password contains both letters *and* numbers/symbols:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\d,`~!@#$%^&*);'[\]\x22{}]).{8,16}$
```

Further improvements possible.